# Angular JS ngx-toastr Error: Module not found: Error: Package path ./public_api is not exported from package

Tags: angularjs, ngx-toastr

./src/app/nav/nav.component.ts:5:0-44 - Error: Module not found: Error: Package path ./public_api is not exported from package C:\Users\Score\demo\DatingApp\client\node_modules\ngx-toastr (see exports field in C:\Users\Score\demo\DatingApp\client\node_modules\ngx-toastr\package.json)

./src/app/register/register.component.ts:4:0-55 - Error: Module not found: Error: Package path ./toastr/toastr.service is not exported from package C:\Users\Score\demo\DatingApp\client\node_modules\ngx-toastr (see exports field in C:\Users\Score\demo\DatingApp\client\node_modules\ngx-toastr\package.json)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaZNB.png

Answer (score 5):

Use this

```
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
```

Instade of

```
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr/public_api';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr/toastr/toastr.service';
```

Answer (score 2):

import toastService in your service file like this:

import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I uninstalled the version I had and instead, I used this command to install the older version:

```
npm i ngx-toastr@14.3.0
```

Hope that solves it for you!